# how to call parameterized method in button click event in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

Ho to Call  method with parameters in Button Click Event:

Here SelectJobsheet returning an **ajax response** and I want to call this method in Button-Click event

```
     [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static object Details4(string selectedJobSheet)
    {

        try
        {
            List<OffDetails> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OffDetails>> 
             (selectedJobSheet);

            string FirstName;
            int Customer_id;
            string details;
            foreach (OffDetails user in users)
            {
                FirstName = user.first_name;
                Customer_id = user.customer_id;
                details = FirstName + "  " + Customer_id;


            }

            return null;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }`
```

ButtonClick:

```
protected void Jobsheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: From a server side perspective, Details4 is just a static method like any other. Did you try calling it from Jobsheet_Click? What was the result? Why are you catching exceptions only to rethrow them?

Comment: I called it in button_click event its expecting parameters of that method

Comment: So? You haven't shown your attempt here at calling it here, nor have you clearly describe the errors you're getting when you try to do so. Show your attempt!

Comment: Hint: you must call it from javascript.